# Backbone.js stop navigation on http error response of form POST

Tags: jquery, node.js, backbone.js

I'm executing an ajax post using a form and I want to be able to present an error under the form in my view if something goes wrong on the server. The ajax inside my view looks like:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/dothis",
        type: "post",
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            console.log("Success response")
                event.preventDefault();
                app.navigate("somewhereelse", true);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Error response")
             event.preventDefault();

            utils.showAlert('Error', xhr.responseText, 'alert-error');
        },
        async: true
    });
```

I can send this error back from node.js:

```
res.send(500, "This is my error");
```

But on error the app navigates away from the form page and back to my index page. how can I get it to not navigate away and instead present the error. Assume correct functioning of the utils.showAlert() because I know that works. It just puts a message in a div of class 'alert'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you return from the server would be an object that looks something like this:

```
{'success': 'some_msg', 'error': 'some_error'}
```

This object will be received in the success callback of the Ajax call.
On either success or error, you will handle the response yourself. 
So the message that you get back from the server will redirect you, because it is part of the success callback.

The error in the 'error' callback function is related to the Ajax call itself, but unrelated from the custom error message that you return from the server yourself.